# JQuery Dropdown (Select/Option) Validation

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, validation

I've been working on this and I'm having issues validating the dropdown.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('#contact_name').on('input', function() {
     var input=$(this);
     var is_name=input.val();
     if(is_name){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
     else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}
    });
    
    $('#contact_email').on('input', function() {
     var input=$(this);
     var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
     var is_email=re.test(input.val());
     if(is_email){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
     else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}
    });
    
    
    $('#contact_message').keyup(function(event) {
     var input=$(this);
     var message=$(this).val();
     console.log(message);
     if(message){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
     else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");} 
    });
  
   $("#contact_submit button").click(function(event){
    var form_data=$("#contact").serializeArray();
    var error_free=true;
    for (var input in form_data){
     var element=$("#contact_"+form_data[input]['name']);
     var valid=element.hasClass("valid");
     var error_element=$("span", element.parent());
     if (!valid){error_element.removeClass("error").addClass("error_show"); error_free=false;}
     else{error_element.removeClass("error_show").addClass("error");}
    }
    if (!error_free){
     event.preventDefault(); 
    }
    else{
     alert('No errors: Form will be submitted');
    }
   });
   
   
   
  });
```

```css
#contact label{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
   text-align: right;
  }
  #contact_submit{
   padding-left: 100px;
  }
  #contact div{
   margin-top: 1em;
  }
  textarea{
   vertical-align: top;
   height: 5em;
  }
   
  .error{
   display: none;
   margin-left: 10px;
  }  
  
  .error_show{
   color: red;
   margin-left: 10px;
  }
  
  input.invalid, textarea.invalid{
   border: 2px solid red;
  }
  
  input.valid, textarea.valid{
   border: 2px solid green;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contact" method="post" action="">
    <!-- Name -->
    <div>
        <label for="contact_name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="name"></input>
        <span class="error">This field is required</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Email -->
    <div>
        <label for="contact_email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="email"></input>
        <span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>                
    </div>                        
    <!--Website -->
    <div>
        <label for="contact_website">Website:</label>
        <input type="url" id="contact_website" name="website"></input>
        <span class="error">A valid url is required</span>                              
    </div>                        
    <!-- Message -->
    <div>
        <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="contact_message" name="message"></textarea>
        <span class="error">This field is required</span>                                               
    </div>  
    <!-- Drop Down -->
    <div>
      <label for="contact_country">Country: </label>
        <select id="contact_country" name="country">
       <option value="DFLT">-- Choose Country --</option>
       <option value="AFG">Afghanistan</option>
       <option value="ALA">Åland Islands</option>
        </select>
     </div>
    <!-- Submit Button -->
    <div id="contact_submit">             
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Please run snippet. I didn't include the Javascript I tried because it's quite a mess but I'd like to know how to achieve that. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Mattfred, But can you also assist there?

Comment: What issue you are facing and what validation do you want to do with dropdown? Explain your requirement clearly.